# Novel. I think by James P Hogan. Has humans studying flying alien wildlife. These animals are passing on learned behaviour in their genes

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, planets, genetics

I read this book about 20-25 years ago. It was a long story with lots of other things I have forgotten.

The part that really stuck in my mind involved human scientists studying flying wildlife on an alien planet. These animals could pass on learned behaviour to their offspring via their genes. The next generation could do things their parents had been taught, or worked out how to do. An example might be hunting techniques.There was no teaching of the young
by their parents.

I read this book many years before I watched a BBC documentary that introduced me to epigenetics. I believe it was written before there was any such theory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this is a recurring theme in Hogan's works

I remember that a similar feature was also discussed in the book [Entoverse](https://www.goodreads.com/it/book/show/849486) (the fourth installment of the [Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giants_(series)) series).

Unluckily my memory is a bit fuzzy on it, but at some point, two characters are talking about some of the new discoveries made possible by their contacts with the Ganymeans and talk about an alien creature (which, if I recall correctly, was also a flying creature) that can pass through the genes all of the notions it learnt in life.
I also remember one of the characters commenting negatively on this, on the lines of the fact that if mankind had such a feature, it would fall hopelessly in the totalitarism.
Of course in that book that creature was only talked about (maybe one of the character had said he was studying one of them in his laboratory), it never appeard "live".

Comment: Yes it is Entoverse. Thank you very much. The passage I remembered was at the beginning of chapter 9. I don't have a copy in a form I can easily copy and paste it from or I would add a quote to your answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You might be thinking of Hogan's [*Code of the Lifemaker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_the_Lifemaker) which features humans finding a society of robots that has evolved on Titan after the crash of alien spaceship; the creatures that have evolved include medieval-level humanoids and various "animals" and "planets" that are made of metal.

Here's the [prologue](http://www.baen.com/chapters/W200203/0743435265___0.htm) to that novel which elaborates on that evolution

> Although the robots' local memories were becoming larger than those
> contained in their earlier ancestors, the operating programs were
> growing in size and complexity too, with the result that an acceptor
> still didn't possess enough free space to hold an entire "How to Make
> a Fred" subfile. The donor's half, therefore, could be accommodated
> only by overwriting some of the code already residing in the acceptor.
> How this was accomplished depended on the responses of the programs
> carried inside the various robot types.
>
> In some cases the incoming code from the donor was allowed to
> overwrite entire program modules inside the acceptor, with the total
> loss to the acceptor of the functions which those modules controlled.
> This was usually fatal, and no descendants came into being to repeat
> such mistakes. The successful alternative was to create space by
> trimming nonessential code from many modules, which tended to leave
> the acceptor robot with some degradation in performance—usually
> manifesting itself as a reduction in agility, dexterity, and defensive
> abilities—but at least still functioning. The sacrifice was only
> temporary since the acceptor robot would be reprogramed with
> replacement modules when it delivered its genetic package at the
> factory.
>
> But in return for these complications and superficial penalties came
> the immense benefit that the subfiles presented at the factories were
> complete ones—suitable for dispatch to the Schedulers without delay
> and the attendant risk of being deleted by overworked Supervisors. The
> new method thus solved the reliability problem that had plagued the
> formerly universal "asexual" mode of reproduction.

Because of the way that code is passed around, evolution here may have some epigenetic features

Comment: Thank you. I definitely did read Code of The Lifemaker at about the same time. It is possible this is what I remember but I think It was a different book involving actual biological flying alien animals.

Comment: In sequels, the creators of the robots were revealed to be an avian species.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is *Legacy* by Greg Bear, which takes place on a planet called "Lamarckia" - a planet where a very small number of very large organisms each control large portions of the planet, creating apparently independent flying, crawling, swimming (etc.) units to serve the purposes of the dispersed organisms. If any of the units experiences something that suggests a better way of doing things, later versions of that unit will use that better way. Each of the "ecos" have flying units, who bite human visitors to sample our genetic information.

Review of *[Legacy](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/greg-bear/legacy-7/)* here:

> A newly discovered planet, Lamarckia, is home to marvelous life-forms
> called "ecoi"; each single "ecos" is composed of bizarre plant/animal
> hybrids known as "scions" analogous to single cells, all of them
> managed, so it is hypothesized, by a "seed-mistress." But then radical
> fanatic Jaime Carr Lenk opens an illegal Way gate and disappears onto
> Lamarckia with 4000 followers. The Hexamon dispatches agent Olmy to
> investigate. Arriving 37 years later, thanks to the uncertainties of
> Way transit, Olmy discovers a brutal war in progress between Lenk
> loyalists and rebellious Brionists. In order to better inspect the
> ecoi, Olmy joins the crew of an oceangoing research vessel. They come
> upon a dead ecos, confirm the seed-mistress hypothesis, and discover
> the skeletal remains of quasihuman scions.

Comment: I will check this one out, thanks again.